# Does changing wildcard record affect other records like mail MX records

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, wildcard

I created a new website using another server.

Pointed the @ record to my new server. However, the result is:

www.domain.com  points to old server
domain.com (without www) points to new server

I checked that *.domain.com is pointed to my old server.

If a point *.domain.com to my new server does other records like mail MX records become broken?

Or, is there any way to point www.domain.com to my new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If a point *.domain.com to my new server does other records like mail
>   MX records become broken?

only if it's a CNAME

> Or, is there any way to point www.domain.com to my new server.

that's what I would do, either cname www to @ or add a second A record.

Comment: the domain holder doesn't allow cname www to @ or * to any ip. It looks like I have to migrate my domain to another server(which I don't want to) and reconfigure all the records.

Comment: so www to the same IP as @

Comment: It worked. Thank You. www to the same ip is @. some domain holders allow www to @, others allow www to ip

Comment: wanna tap the accept button

Answer (score 1):

> If I point *.example.com to my new server do other records like mail MX records become broken?

A wildcard record is only applied when a more specific record does not exist, so adding it won't impact any of your already existing DNS records and you can always override a wildcard if you need to.

Comment: When I try to edit *.domain.com the system doesn't allow me to do so. Is there any other way? For example creating a CNAME like below: from www to domain.com does it work? I don't want to mess up anything :)